# Nginx - multiple WordPress sites in different subdirectories - /wp-admin redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I am attempting to host three separate WordPress sites in three different directories with Nginx. After hours of research, I am completely unable to find a configuration that allows me to access both `/wp-admin` and various pages on the site.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www;
        server_name my.ip.add.ress;

        location /wp1 {
            root /var/www/wp1;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /wp1/index.php?q=$args;
        }

        location /wp2 {
            root /var/www/wp2;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /wp2/index.php?q=$args;
        }

        location /wp3 {
            root /var/www/wp3;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /wp3/index.php?q=$args;
        }

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
            rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+.*(/wp-admin/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
            rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
        }   

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

                try_files           $uri =404;

                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;

                fastcgi_cache moodle;
                fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;

                fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
        }

        # Cache static content
        location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
                expires 365d;
        }
}
```

When I try to access /wp-admin, my browser is stuck in a redirect loop. Using rewrite_log yields no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you question you have this:

```
root /var/www;
...
location /wp1 {
    root /var/www/wp1;
    ...
}
```

The pathname for `/wp1/foo` is resolved as `/var/www/wp1/wp1/foo`. Notice that you have added a second `/wp1/` term into the pathname.

Inside `location /wp1` the root does not change. You do not need to specify `root` inside each of the locations, because it remains `root /var/www;` which will be inherited from the outer block anyway.

Delete the lines:

```
root /var/www/wp1; 
root /var/www/wp2; 
root /var/www/wp3;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for more.